# How can I compare the date of the model in a view and current date

Tags: html, asp.net-core, view

How can I check if the orderdate is today or tomorrow? OrderDate is datetime attribute.

```html
if(@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate == today)
{
<div>Today</div>
}
else if(@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate == today+1)
{
  <div>Tomorrow</div>
}
else{
<div>@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate </div>
}
```

e is todays date in the view

Comment: Hi, I already posted the code to solve your question. It works on me. If the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date property on DateTime.Now for today and AddDays(1) for Tomorrow.

```
If(@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
{
<div>Today</div>
}
else if(@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date)
{
  <div>Tomorrow</div>
}
else{
<div>@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test of result:**

[image]

> Codes for View

```
@model Orders

@{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
    DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);

}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderList.Count; i++)
{
    if (@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate == today)
    {
        <div>@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate.ToShortDateString() is Today</div>
    }
    else if (@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate == tomorrow)
    {
        <div>@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate.ToShortDateString() is Tomorrow</div>
    }
    else if(@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate == yesterday)
    {
        <div>@Model.OrderList[i].Orderdate.ToShortDateString() is Yesterday</div>
    }
}
```

> Codes for Controller

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Orders orders = new Orders();
        orders.OrderList.Add(new OrderDate()
        {
            Orderdate = DateTime.Parse("07/16/2020") //today
        }); 
        orders.OrderList.Add(new OrderDate()
        {
            Orderdate = DateTime.Parse("07/17/2020") //tomorrow
        });
        orders.OrderList.Add(new OrderDate()
        {
            Orderdate = DateTime.Parse("07/15/2020") //yesterday
        }); 

        return View(orders);
    }
```

> Codes for Model

```
public class Orders
{
    public Orders() {
        OrderList = new List<OrderDate>();
    }
    public List<OrderDate> OrderList { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDate
{
    public DateTime Orderdate { get; set; }

}
```